# Store Value from On/Off Button in MySQL Database Using PHP Ajax code throwing error

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, mysqli, pdo

I have tried the exact same code on the link :-  http://www.freezecoders.com/2013/05/store-value-from-onoff-button-in-mysql-database-using-php-ajax.html

Index.php :

```
<?php
$query=mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
mysql_select_db("freeze",$query);
?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head profile="http://gmpg.org/xfn/11">
<title>iPhone Style Radio and Checkbox Switches, found on DevGrow.com</title>
<script type="text/javascript"src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#myonoffswitch').click(function(){
var myonoffswitch=$('#myonoffswitch').val();
if ($("#myonoffswitch:checked").length == 0)
{
var a=myonoffswitch;
}
else
{
var a="off";
}

$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: "ajax.php",
data: "value="+a ,
success: function(html){
$("#display").html(html).show();
}
});

});
});
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready( function(){
$(".cb-enable").click(function(){
var parent = $(this).parents('.switch');
$('.cb-disable',parent).removeClass('selected');
$(this).addClass('selected');
$('.checkbox',parent).attr('checked', true);
});
$(".cb-disable").click(function(){
var parent = $(this).parents('.switch');
$('.cb-enable',parent).removeClass('selected');
$(this).addClass('selected');
$('.checkbox',parent).attr('checked', false);
});
});
</script>

<style type="text/css">
.onoffswitch {
position: relative; width: 90px;
-webkit-user-select:none; -moz-user-select:none; -ms-user-select: none;
}
.onoffswitch-checkbox {
display: none;
}
.onoffswitch-label {
display: block; overflow: hidden; cursor: pointer;
border: 2px solid #999999; border-radius: 20px;
}
.onoffswitch-inner {
width: 200%; margin-left: -100%;
-moz-transition: margin 0.3s ease-in 0s; -webkit-transition: margin 0.3s ease-in 0s;
-o-transition: margin 0.3s ease-in 0s; transition: margin 0.3s ease-in 0s;
}
.onoffswitch-inner:before, .onoffswitch-inner:after {
float: left; width: 50%; height: 30px; padding: 0; line-height: 30px;
font-size: 14px; color: white; font-family: Trebuchet, Arial, sans-serif; font-weight: bold;
-moz-box-sizing: border-box; -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; box-sizing: border-box;
}
.onoffswitch-inner:before {
content: "OFF";
padding-left: 10px;
background-color: #2FCCFF; color: #FFFFFF;
}
.onoffswitch-inner:after {
content: "ON";
padding-right: 10px;
background-color: #EEEEEE; color: #999999;
text-align: right;
}
.onoffswitch-switch {
width: 18px; margin: 6px;
background: #FFFFFF;
border: 2px solid #999999; border-radius: 20px;
position: absolute; top: 0; bottom: 0; right: 56px;
-moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-in 0s; -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in 0s;
-o-transition: all 0.3s ease-in 0s; transition: all 0.3s ease-in 0s;
}
.onoffswitch-checkbox:checked + .onoffswitch-label .onoffswitch-inner {
margin-left: 0;
}
.onoffswitch-checkbox:checked + .onoffswitch-label .onoffswitch-switch {
right: 0px;
}
</style>

</head>
<body>
<div class="onoffswitch">
<input type="checkbox" name="onoffswitch" class="onoffswitch-checkbox" id="myonoffswitch"
<?php
$query3=mysql_query("select * from choice where id=1");
$query4=mysql_fetch_array($query3);
if($query4['choice']=="off")
{
echo "checked";
}
?>>
<label class="onoffswitch-label" for="myonoffswitch">
<div class="onoffswitch-inner"></div>
<div class="onoffswitch-switch"></div>
</label>
</div>

<div id="display"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

And this ajax.php:-

```
<?php
$query=mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
mysql_select_db("freeze",$query);
if(isset($_POST['value']))
{
$value=$_POST['value'];
mysql_query("update choice set choice='$value' where id='1'");
echo "<h2>You have Chosen the button status as:" .$value."</h2>";
}
?>
```

But the fact is it is not working on my wamp server. This code throws a lot of errors such as : Deprecated: mysql_connect(): The mysql extension is deprecated and will be removed in the future: use mysqli or PDO instead in C:\wamp\www\btn\index.php on line 2 
and :- mysqli_fetch_array() error on the line 109 . What is the problem with the given code ? Is there any one who can help me with this ?

Answer (score 1):

The answer is already in your error posted by you in Question..
you are using older mysql methods which are deprecated in new php thus you have to use mysqli(improved mysql) methods.

Replace all your mysql with mysqli commands with proper syntax..check mysqli documentation online if required ..

for eg - replace mysql_connect with mysqli_connect and other mysql commands as well..

I hope it will solve your problem.

Answer (score -1):

```
 <input type="checkbox" id="<?=$row['id']?>"  name="onoffswitch" value="<?=$row['status']?>" class="js-switch" <?=$row['status'] == '1' ? 'checked' : '' ;?>/> 

$('input[name=onoffswitch]').click(function(){
var id=$(this).attr('id');
var status = $(this).val();
if(status == 1) {
    status = 0; 
} else {
    status = 1; 
}
//alert(id);
$.ajax({
        type:'POST',
        url:'updateustaus.php',
        data:'id= ' + id + '&status='+status
    });
});
```

Comment: Please add some explanation, otherwise it's difficult to understand the point you're making.